# JIRA trigger plugin is not working if Jenkins is configured with HTTPS

Tags: jenkins, https, jira, webhooks, jenkins-jira-trigger

I have JIRA and Jenkins installed locally on my system. Jira is installed with http on port 8082 and Jenkins is configured with https on port 443.
I have configured Jira Trigger Plugin which triggers Jenkins build if status is changed in JIRA, it works fine when Jenkins is launched with http on port 8083.
Webhook URL - http://localhost:8083/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/

It does not work when jenkins is launched with https on port 443.
Webhook URL - https://localhost/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/

I downloaded ".pem" file (security file) from Jenkins server (https://localhost) and added it into the keystore of JIRA (E:\JIRA\8.5.1\Install\jre\lib\security\cacerts) on my local installation but I was not able to trigger jenkins build based on JIRA status change.
I went ahead and added ".pem" in every "cacerts" keystore of every java which is installed on my system but still it was not working for me.
Can anybody please help me here, what am I missing when it comes to configuring webhook for jenkins server if jenkins is configured with https.

Comment: Do you have any information in the Jira or Jenkins logs?

Comment: In the logs of both tools i could not see any record for this trigger

Comment: I was going through this link - https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin. In troubleshoot section it is mentioned to set jenkins logging at fine level. I set it to fine level and I was able to see "Received Webhook callback ..." log messages in Jenkins but this was the observation when jenkins was launched as http, if jenkins is launched with https then I dont see any logs in jenkins and webhook is also not triggering

Comment: And nothing in `atlassian-jira.log`?

Comment: nothing which could give me something on wehbook

Comment: Can you trigger Jenkins with curl?

Comment: can you please give me detailed instructions, I am using windows and curl does not exist on the system

Comment: Well whatever tool you normally use to make http requests from the command line, just hit Jenkins and make sure it is really listening where you think it is.

Comment: I had done `telnet localhost 443` and i was able to connect on the port. Additionally I am accessing jenkins on this url - https://localhost.

Comment: I installed curl on my system and run this command `curl https://localhost/jira-trigger-webhook-receiver/` output is `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.`

Comment: Curl gives this output but I added security certificate provided by jenkins into the truststore of JIRA and still I was not able to trigger jenkins job based on Jira status change if jenkins is launched with https